# VBS script to report AD groups - Regex pattern not working with multiple matches

Tags: regex, vbscript, dsquery

Having an issue with getting a regex statement to accept two expressions.

The "re.pattern" code here works:

```
If UserChoice = "" Then WScript.Quit  'Detect Cancel
re.Pattern = "[^(a-z)^(0,4,5,6,7,8,9)]"
re.Global = True    
re.IgnoreCase = True
if re.test( UserChoice ) then 
   Exit Do
 End if
 MsgBox "Please choose either 1, 2 or 3 ", 48, "Invalid Entry"
```

While the below "regex.pattern " code does not. I want to use it to format the results of a DSQUERY command where groups are collected, but I don't want any of the info after the ",", nor do i want the leading CN= that is normally collected when the following dsquery is run:
**"dsquery.exe user forestroot -samid "& strInput &" | dsget user -memberof")**

The string I want to format would look something like this before formatting:

CN=APP_GROUP_123,OU=Global Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=biz

This is the result I want:

APP_GROUP_123

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
**regEx.Pattern = "[,.*]["CN=]"**
Result = regEx.Replace(StrLine, "")
```

I'm only able to get the regex to work when used individually, either

```
   regEx.Pattern = ",."
```

or

```
regEx.Pattern = "CN="
```

code is nested here:

```
Set InputFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("Temp.txt", 1)
Set InputFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("Temp.txt", 1)
set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(StrInput & "-Results.txt", 8, True)

do While InputFile.AtEndOfStream = False
    StrLine = InputFile.ReadLine
      If inStr(strLine, TaskChoice) then    
     Set regEx = New RegExp
     regEx.Pattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}=(.+?),.*"
     Result = regEx.Replace(StrLine, "")
     OutputFile.write(Replace(Result,"""","")) & vbCrLf
      End if
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the string you're performing the regex on, and the result you want to have?

Comment: Added info as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
str = "CN=APP_GROUP_123,OU=Global Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=biz"
Set re = New RegExp
re.pattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}=(.+?),.*"

if re.Test(str) then
    set matches = re.Execute(str)
    matched_str = "Matched: " & matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    Wscript.echo matched_str
else
    Wscript.echo "Not a match"
end if
```

**Output:**`Matched: APP_GROUP_123`

The regex you need is `[A-Za-z]{2}=(.+?),.*`

If the match is successful, it captures everything in the parenthesis. `.+?` means it will match any character *non-greedily* up until the first comma. The `?` in `.+?` makes the expression non-greedy. If you were to omit it, you would capture everything up to the final comma at `,DC=biz`

Comment: Ok! Thanks for answering so quickly, thing is, the CN= and group info will change, really, i just want everything after the "," and the leading "CN=" info removed. What would work to achieve that?

Comment: Ok, should i set the str to the StrLine? That line i gave was just a sample, but the groups that are read are dynamic, and there can be dozens.

I forgot to include the full code at the end, will add to OP now.

Comment: You don't need to do the replace. `matches(0).Submatches(0)` will contain the text you want. Just put that into a variable and write that variable to the file. You need to execute the `regEx.Execute()` method on your input string which I think is `strLine` - whatever will contain "CN=..."

Comment: Works! Thx!

For my own reference - as i'll probably be doing this again at some point - Can you explain how "[A-Za-z]{2}=(.+?)" removes the stuff I 
didn't want? Is it basically saying: Remove anything that looks like  "XX=" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `"[,.*]["CN=]"` doesn't work for 2 reasons:

1. It contains an unescaped double quote. Double quotes inside VBScript strings must be escaped by doubling them, otherwise the interpreter would interpret your expression as a string `"[,.*]["`, followed by an (invalid) variablename `CN=]` (without an operator too) and the beginning of the next string (the 3<sup>rd</sup> double quote).
2. You misunderstand [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax. Square brackets indicate a character class. An expression `[,.*]` would match any single comma, period or asterisk, **not** a comma followed by any number of characters.

   What you meant to use was an alternation, which is expressed by a pipe symbol (`|`), and the beginning of a string is matched by a caret (`^`):

   ```
    regEx.Pattern = ",.*|^CN="
   ```

With that said, in your case a better approach would be using a group and replacing the whole string with just the group match:

```
regEx.Pattern = "^cn=(.*?),.*"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True

Result = regEx.Replace(strLine, "$1")
```

Comment: THx! This solution is elegant, but i'm still noting the following output to the 'results.txt' when I changed the pattern to "^cn=(.*?),.*"

"CN=GROUPABC-123,OU=ABC,OU=Accounts,DC=dom1,DC=corp,DC=contonso,DC=net"

Comment: I ended up going with the solution proposed by arco444. The one you provided was less code, and was close to what i was using, but didn't end up working.